# #import directive search rules

Tags: c++, com, interop

I am having difficulties with understanding the following sentence from MSDN article about the #import directive:

> The path specified by the /I (additional include directories) compiler
>   option, **except it the compiler is searching for a type library that
>   was referenced from another type library with the no_registry
>   attribute.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6(v=vs.100).aspx

Could you please clarify on the part marked with bold?

Comment: Hmm, no, that's backwards.  Substitute "except it" with "and used when".

Comment: Is this mean that the compiler consider the /I option only for #import-statements with no_registry attribute?

Comment: This only applies to type libraries that the #imported one uses with the auto_search attribute applied.  Best avoided, I prefer to #import them explicitly.